# Creating an instance of a Movieclip with event.target information

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to access the type of object being interacted with so I can create a new instance of the same object? So for example in the code below I have the movieclip myItem. After it's clicked it is removed from stage and then moved to the inventory. When I click on it there, is it possible to create a new instance of mcItemToDuplicate using the event information parameters? (while allowing myItem to be where it is).

My code looks something like this:

```
public function moveclip() {
    var myItem:mcItemToDuplicate = new mcItemToDuplicate();
    stage.addChild(myItem);
    myItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pickUp);
}

private function pickUp(e:MouseEvent){
    stage.removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));
    MovieClip(e.target).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pickUp);

    inventory.addChild(MovieClip(e.target));
    MovieClip(e.target).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useItem);
}

private function useItem(e:MouseEvent){
//??
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[flash.utils package](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package-detail.html) has some methods that you might find useful.

```
import flash.utils.*;

//use currentTarget; target might be different.
var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget);
var type:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
var obj:Sprite = new type();//datatype of var obj can be Sprite or MovieClip
                            //or just Object depending on how you plan to use it
something.addChild(obj);
```

Comment: Ah, great thats just what I needed. Thanks alot.